# How to use Webpack.ProvidePlugin to load user defined global object?

Tags: webpack

I know you can use ProvidePlugin to inject every jQuery to modules who is using it.

```
plugins: [
    new Webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: "jquery",
        jQuery: "jquery",
    })
  ],
```

There is a my own utility module in global space, I'd like to use ProvidePlugin to load, just like jQuery, how do I do it?

```
 plugins: [ 
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        'mtUtilities': '../Presentation/Base/Default/js/source/_common/mtUtilities.js'
    })
 ],
```

The above code will result an path error. The program can't find 'mtUtilities' since the path is relative, so it is wrong. How to fix it?

Comment: if i'm not wrong, you just have to include your `mtUtilities.js` in your html `<script>` tag and config would look like `plugins: [ 
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        'mtUtilities': 'mtUtilities'
    })
 ],`

Answer (score 1):

Below should work.

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    'mtUtilities': __dirname + '/../Presentation/Base/Default/js/source/_common/mtUtilities.js'
})
```